# Apk closes when switching between pages

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to go to page two from the first page. I don't think there is an error with the code. Why does the apk turn off when you press the page switch button?

You may not understand me because I don't speak English.

In short, why does the apk close when you press the button?

Main xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="#00ccff"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text=""
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/guzelsozlerbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Değiştir"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:onClick="guzelsoz"
        />

    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main java activitiy

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    
    Button guzelsozler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        guzelsozler = findViewById(R.id.guzelsozlerbtn);
    }
    public void guzelsoz(View view) 
    {
        Intent guzelsozsayfasi = new Intent (MainActivity.this,guzelsozler.class);
        startActivity(guzelsozsayfasi);
    }
}
```

Comment: what error is showing in your  logcat?

Comment: No error / hata göstermiyor

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared **guzelsozler** in your app's manifest.

```
<activity  
    android:name=".guzelsozler"  
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"/>
```

Comment: I don't know what it has to do with the Manifesto.   
    
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: The manifest file describes essential information about your app to the Android build tools. Every activity that you want to launch and start in your application must be declared in android manifest. Open **AndroiMnifest.xml** and add your activity like what I wrote above inside application tag.

Answer (score 0):

The function is not needed for what you are trying to achieve. You want to start an Activity from `MainActivity` on Button pressed. You can do it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    
    Button guzelsozler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        guzelsozler = findViewById(R.id.guzelsozlerbtn);
        guzelsozler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent guzelsozsayfasi = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(guzelsozsayfasi);
        }
    });
        
}
```

Notice that I used `new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class)`. This `SecondActivity` is the Activity you want to show. Your `guzelsozler.class` was not correct since that is the variable name for your `Button`. So, provide the second parameter which is `Activity.class` whatever the name of that `Activity` is.

Comment: No, sir. APK closing

Comment: Can you please share AndroidManifest with us? Did you create new Activity like you did with MainActivity?

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  android:resizeableActivity = "true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

Comment: As much as I can see you don't have an activity created inside AndroidManifest.xml. Do you have a layout for guzelsozler and guzelsozler.class inside java directory?

Comment: On the left side where you have MainActivity, do you have anything else besides MainActivity?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);           
    }

    public void guzelsoz(View view) 
    {
        Intent guzelsozsayfasi = new Intent (this,guzelsozler.class);
        startActivity(guzelsozsayfasi);
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
<application> 
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" > 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".guzelsozler"  /> 

 </application>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the apk closes again

Comment: can you tell me your another activity name

Comment: guzelsozler <---

Comment: add <activity  
    android:name=".guzelsozler"  
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"/> in your manifest file

Comment: @RahulPareta don't teach him that. You can see that his button is named guzelsozler, so he thinks he needs to provide that to start another activity. We don't know how he named other activities, or if he even has any at this point. That is shooting blindfolded and it could only confuse him or mess up his project. .... Cebom25, please provide your AndroidManifest.xml file in your quesiton.

Comment: @SlothCoding his decond activity name is "guzelsozler" please check previous comments

Comment: Well, he said that, but do you think that Android Studio would allow him to create a variable named guzelsozler which is an instance of a Button while he has an Activity named the same way?

Comment: @SlothCoding why not?

Comment: I just want it to go to Page Two when I press the button.

Comment: @RahulPareta oh sorry, I actually tested it right now and it can work but then it's confusing. Because when you provide the second parameter inside the new Intent() it could read from variable guzelsozler and not checking the activity class.

Comment: @Cebom25 can you change the button name to something else, like guzelbtn, and then try?

Comment: @SlothCoding it won't read from variable we add guzelsozler.class basically problem is that he haven't added activity in his manifest file

Comment: changing and trying

Comment: sending to the same page